# There was an unexpected failure with this assessment, invalid type provided

Tags: servicenow

I'm attempting to run the following code which is pretty much copied from the OoTheBox UI Action called "View User's Response".

```
function showRiskAssessment(){
    var ra = new GlideRecord('asmt_assessment_instance');
    ra.addQuery('task_id', '=', current.sys_id);
    ra.orderByDesc('taken_on');
    ra.setLimit(1);
    ra.query();
    
    // var id = g_form.getUniqueValue();
    var id = ra.sys_id;
    //var type = g_form.getValue('metric_type');
    var type = '468aeff2db9357008aeba9f7059619ca';
    var url = 'assessment_take2.do?sysparm_assessable_sysid=' + id + '&sysparm_assessable_type=' + type + '&sysparm_reader_view=true';

    var d = new GlideOverlay({
        title: "User's Response",
        iframe: url,
        width:'80%',
        height: '100%',
        onAfterLoad: function() {
            var iframe = d.getIFrameElement();
            setTimeout(function(){
                iframe.height = parseInt(iframe.height)+1;
            },0);
        }
    });
    d.render();
}
```

If I hardcode it like this it works.  All I'm trying to do is on the change record I want to look up the most recent Assessment Instance for that particular change and display in the overlay.  Obviously I can't hardcode the `id` however it seems the query isn't recognizing that info at all anyways.

```
function showRiskAssessment(){
    // var ra = new GlideRecord('asmt_assessment_instance');
    // ra.addQuery('task_id', '=', current.sys_id);
    // ra.orderByDesc('taken_on');
    // ra.setLimit(1);
    // ra.query();
    
    // var id = g_form.getUniqueValue();
    var id = '5c516eeddb87d090ebce60ab1396198a';
    //var type = g_form.getValue('metric_type');
    var type = '468aeff2db9357008aeba9f7059619ca';
    var url = 'assessment_take2.do?sysparm_assessable_sysid=' + id + '&sysparm_assessable_type=' + type + '&sysparm_reader_view=true';

    var d = new GlideOverlay({
        title: "User's Response",
        iframe: url,
        width:'80%',
        height: '100%',
        onAfterLoad: function() {
            var iframe = d.getIFrameElement();
            setTimeout(function(){
                iframe.height = parseInt(iframe.height)+1;
            },0);
        }
    });
    d.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use **current.sys_id** in a client side script. It is recommended to use **g_form** for client side scripts. You're also trying a GlideRecord on a client script, which is also not recommended.

To fix, replace:

```
ra.addQuery('task_id', '=', current.sys_id);
```

with:

```
var sysId = g_form.getUniqueValue();
ra.addQuery('task_id', '=', sysId);
```

Also, for the difference between g_form and current have a look [here](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=e1bfa278db9fa3009540e15b8a961938).